# Post Image(Image is from gallery ) with link (ex: http://www.google.com) on facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is my requirement in my project 
I have to post image on a friends wall,The image is from gallery  and with a link(Ex:http://www.google.com). When I click on the image it should navigate to the link.

When I referred the facebook GraphApi the topic "post" they said that the picture value should contain the URL type.But my requirement is that the  image should be from gallery ,it doesn't contain  a URL.

Could any one help in achieving this

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

> But my requirement is that the image should be from gallery ,it doesn't contain a URL.

Not sure what this is supposed to mean.

But maybe you want to post a *link* to a specific URL, that points to a page that *displays* that very image, and contains Open Graph meta tags to tell Facebook what the thumbnail image, description etc, should be.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

http://ogp.me/

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,actually my requirement is that I want to post an image from the android default gallery ,and that image should post on the wall with some website url ,and on clicking the image it should go to that particular website url.Could u please tell how to achieve this

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos You have to POST the data as `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`; the link to the website you can put into the message parameter.